# Is snakeyaml 2.0 added in the new Spring boot versions?

Tags: spring-boot, snakeyaml

I see there is reference to snakeyaml 2.0 in the bugfixes of the new SPringBoot release 3.10-M2 & the older version, but when we look at the source code, we see that the snakeyaml library version is still 1.33

Is there a way to get more information on this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.7.x ([since 2.7.10](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34405)) and 3.0.x ([since 3.0.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34515)) releases are compatible with SnakeYAML 2.0 but do not use it by default. They do not use 2.0 by default for backwards compatibility. SnakeYAML 2.0 was released after Spring Boot 2.7.0 and 3.0.0 were released and [Spring Boot does not upgrade to new major versions of dependencies in its maintenance releases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Team-Practices#third-party-dependency-upgrades) as doing so could be a breaking change depending on how an application itself and other dependencies are using SnakeYAML.

Spring Boot 3.2.0 (release date TBA as of November 9, 2023) will update SnakeYaml from 1.33 to 2.2.

Comment: Thanks Andy, so to include Snakeyaml 2.0, I need to build it from the source, right?

Comment: No. SnakeYAML 2.0 is available from Maven Central. You can use it in a Spring Boot application by overriding the `snakeyaml.version` property in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. There's no need to build anything from source.

Comment: Thanks, What would happen if we overide snakeyaml 2.0 dependency in an unsupported spring version. I ask that because when i tried it, the code that i was running was working .

Comment: @VinodK Which version are you using? It should be fine with 2.7.10 or later and 3.0.5 or later.

Comment: @VinodK In that case (where it's an unsupported version) I think you have to assume that stuff may well break, but not immediately. Might seem tempting to just call it good and carry on, but you could easily end up with weird classpath errors that start cropping up now and then.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Is there a reason snakeyaml wasn't updated to 2.0 in SB 3.1.0, given it's compatible and the docs say "a minor version of Spring Boot could include a major or minor version upgrade of a third-party dependency"?

Comment: @MichaelBerry IIRC, there were parts of the ecosystem that are covered by Spring Boot's dependency management that were not compatible with SnakeYAML 2.0 by the time we reached RC1. We'll look again at raising the default to 2.0 in Spring Boot 3.2.