# What's the highest version of Snakeyaml compatible with Spring Boot 1.X?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, snakeyaml

I would like to upgrade to the latest version of SnakeYaml that is compatible with Spring Boot 1.X.

I'm constrained considerably by the existing use of spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client which is currently 1.4.3.

I'm having difficulty finding this information. Is there any more reliable / easy way to determine what versions introduce breaking changes?

#### Other info

- There is a longer term project going on to upgrade to Spring Boot 2, but in the short term I would like to reduce the security vulnerabilities that I could be exposed to.
- There is a change history here: https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Changes

Comment: do you accept yaml from untrusted sources?

Comment: No. In practice that means we're probably ok but as a long term fix I need to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parent POM of your maven project, if it is a maven project, of course. You can check the updatable transitive dependencies of your project with the maven versions plugin too using :

- `mvn dependency:tree` to display your dependencies.
- `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` to see which ones you need to
  update.

Some dependencies matrix are often given on projects documentations sheets. Consult them to see which ones fits for your project with Spring Boot 1.X.

When you will go further with your upgrade to Spring Boot 2.x version, you should consider these informations too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75875594/390462

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess I'm able to obtain the equivalent info for gradle. But how is this compatibility sourced? I'm assuming it's the library's build descriptor. I'm not sure that gives an exhaustive listing of the compatible versions.

Comment: Maybe you could check, if not already done, this gradle versions plugin : https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin

Comment: And yes, your spring boot parent pom is containing the snakeyaml dependency version for your application using Spring Boot 1.X... if these dependency is managed by the framework. You can upgrade until you are facing any kind of functional failure, incompatibility/regression... it is time consuming to check that of course... but you can try using test suites of related softwares you are using (snakeyaml + spring cloud netflix eureka client + spring boot 1.x).