# implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0' doesn't work even with springboot 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, snakeyaml, trivy

I have upgraded from `Springboot 2.7.12` to `3.1.0` in order to upgrade `Snakeyaml` dependency to 2.0 version, which isn't vulnerable. That required gradle and java version upgrade.

However, now I'm getting the below error, thre `2.0 snakeyaml` isn't compatible. How to work that around?

```
16:38:31.540 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method 'void <init>()' not found
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.createYaml(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedYamlLoader.load(OriginTrackedYamlLoader.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadDocuments(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:632)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:534)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:501)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:471)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$7(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:450)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$8(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:450)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:447)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$load$0(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:350)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.FilteredPropertySource.apply(FilteredPropertySource.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at rf.dom.billing.ap.Application.main(Application.java:24)
```

Comment: Related: [Is snakeyaml 2.0 added in the new Spring boot versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870282/is-snakeyaml-2-0-added-in-the-new-spring-boot-versions) ([this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870282/is-snakeyaml-2-0-added-in-the-new-spring-boot-versions#comment133864016_75875594) in particular).

Comment: As per my testing, Spring Boot `3.1.0` (even `3.1.2`) + SnakeYAML `2.0` works. There is no issue reading config properties from a YAML config file in `src/main/resources`. Perhaps you can share an MVP project that can show that it fails.